# Is there an way to find the history of a deleted folder in bitbucket , if it was deleted in a merge?

Tags: git, bitbucket, merge-conflict-resolution

One folder ,'xyz' in tests folder was deleted in a code merge.
As it is a code merge, I am not able to see and prove that the folder 'xyz' was deleted in merge.
This information is not seen in history as well.
Is there any way to get this log or to prove this?

I located the commit id where the issue happened and noticed that the folder 'xyz' that was present in the previous commit is missing after the particular merge.
I downloaded the two commits code and checked this manually

Comment: git only tracks files. you can show when a file was deleted with `git diff --stat  before_merge..merge -- xyz`

Comment: Thankyou for response, Can I use ' git diff ' with respect to two merge IDs as this happened almost a month back and many merges and code pushes happened after that..

Comment: Yes. Insert the SHAs. `git diff --stat sha_before_merge..sha_merge -- xyz`

Answer (score 1):

Folders do not have history in git; only files are actually tracked, and a folder can be thought of to "exist" in a commit if (and only if) any files within that folder exist.

That is, if any file matches the worktree path `path/to/folder/*` or `path/to/folder/**/*`, then `path/to/folder` will exist in the work tree (so that the files can exist); but if no such files exist, neither will the folder.

So you really want to see (or prove) when *the last file within the folder* was removed.  You could start with the logs

```
git checkout master  # or whatever branch was merged into, from which the folder disappeared
git log --first-parent -n 1 -- tests/xyz
```

(where `tests/xyz` is the path to the deleted folder, as understood from your question).

This will tell you the most recent commit (including merge commits but not breaking out the individual commits of the merged-in branches) on `master` that changed anything under `tests/xyz`  You could grab the SHA from that result and do something lke

```
git diff --name-status <sha> ^<sha>^ -- tests/xyz
```

to confirm what was done to each path under `tests/xyz` by that merge.  (The second `<sha>` argument starts and ends with a `^`; the trailing `^` means "parent commit of", and the leading `^` means "exclude history reachable from this".)

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to see and prove that the folder 'xyz' was deleted in merge

You certainly are (if it was).  If content is present in all parents of a commit and not present in that commit, it was deleted by that commit.

The simplest check for humans for this specific situation is probably

```
git rev-parse $merge^1:tests/xyz $merge^2:tests/xyz $merge:tests/xyz
```

and if that shows two id's and then errors out, the the xyz folder was deleted during the merge.  Git's automerge simply does not delete content that exists in both parents.  The only way to get this result is to delete all the contents manually during conflict resolution, or a `--no-commit` or otherwise custom merge or some later `git commit --amend` equivalent.

In a script I'd feed the expressions into `git cat-file --batch-check` because that doesn't error out on a missing rev:

```
printf %s:tests/xyz\\n $merge $merge^1 $merge^2 | git cat-file --batch-check
```